# Limits for shell parameters

Tags: terminal

Why is the maximum allowed parameters for a shell script (for example, run with the terminal) 65535?  Why not a different number?  Why so... huge?

Comment: There is not such thing like infinity in computers that we know. Or there is something (1) or not (0).

Comment: Well, close to infinity.  I apologize for being vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

65535 happens to be 2<sup>16</sup> - 1, which is the maximum number than can be represented in an unsigned 16-bit integer. At the time the software was designed, that was probably close enough to "infinity" for all practical purposes. Today, with 64-bit machines on every desktop, it seems quaintly small, yet still far more than you would ever use for a shell script.